# Using PHP djjob

Tags: php, plugins, delayed-job

I'm trying to use [djjob](https://github.com/seatgeek/djjob), a PHP port of delayed_job, but I really don't understand how to use it; the documentation is pretty short, and not very explanatory. Could somebody just show me a simple task that uses djjob? Thanks

Comment: As far as I can see there is a simple example task https://github.com/seatgeek/djjob/blob/master/README.textile

Comment: Are you familiar with djjob in ruby ?